# NodeJS how to make a special get CRUD

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing some nodeJS code in which I want to make a get request and the result of this get must respect two condition the first is that the `imei.name` is passed in parameeteres `req.query.imei` and the second condition is that the test filed is not empty that's my `MongoDb` database.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7f90fb88d8d4d94184333"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bokhhjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7fb9cb88d8d4d94184334"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354",
                "modele" : "CPH1803"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba73395fd8dd073065efdf"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bok55555555555hjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0f93c0c93ec1c785358ab"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354"
        },
        "test" : {
                "tactileState" : "1",
                "pixelState" : "1",
                "greyState" : "1"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T11:59:56.441Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T11:59:56.441Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0f9420c93ec1c785358ac"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354"
        },
        "test" : {
                "tactileState" : "1",
                "pixelState" : "1",
                "greyState" : "1"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T12:00:02.040Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T12:00:02.040Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I tried to write this method but without any result

```
router.get('/gettdata/', (req, res, next) => {
   
    let aa=req.query.imei;
    console.log(aa);
    Post.findOne( 
    imei:{"imei.name":req.query.imei},
 test: {$exists:true})

      .then((posts) => {
        res.json(posts);
        console.log(posts);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
  });
```

Comment: what are the logs?

Comment: your code doesn't have valid syntax. I doubt it will run. `Post.findOne` takes an object.

Comment: [] an emty fields like this

Comment: Post.findOne return null

Comment: Seems like findOne syntax is wrong. It should be `Post.findOne({'imei.name': req.query.imei, test: { $exists: true } })`.

Comment: it reurns only the id and only one fields